# Epub 2.O: font in ul, ol lists is smaller than regular font

Tags: epub, font-rendering

I'm formatting an ebook that has taught me many things ... usually after a fair bit of angst, consultation of manuals, online sleuthing, and experimentation. (This is a complicated non-fiction book, with an appendix containing 102 entries, each with five paragraph styles and embedded images.) I have solved everything, it validates but ... the font displayed in ul and ol lists is smaller than the font in the rest of the book.

I do not have any list styles defined. I thought that the list took its style from the paragraph style unless otherwise specified.

I do not recall having run into this problem on other books, some of which had lists. Could the problem be that this is the first time that I have used an imbedded font, at the client's request?

The paragraph .css looks like this:

```
  font-family:"texgyreschola", serif;
  font-size:1.0em;
  text-indent:1.5em; 
  text-align: left; 
  margin-top:0; 
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-right:.5em;
```

Is the font-embedding somehow interfering with list display? If it is, how do I fix things? Create a list style and duplicate the paragraph specs?

I will be abjectly grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` will not inherit from `<p>`, so what you are seeing is probably a different font in your lists than in your paragraphs. The easiest way I've found to test this is to add something impossible to mistake to the CSS for `<p>`. I like to use `color: red`, but your mileage may vary.

Note that the reason that the fonts could appear to be different sizes is that some fonts look bigger than others—compare Open Sans and Times New Roman, for example, and the Times will look substantially smaller, even though both are 1.0em.

Including

```
li {
  font-family:"texgyreschola", serif;
  font-size:1.0em;
}
```

in your CSS should do the trick.

Comment: It worked! It worked! I am indeed abjectly grateful.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you're all squared away, you could mark this answer as accepted.